# RPC function returns stuct; values junk in client

Tags: c, rpc

Problem: In Solaris RPC, i am returning a struct from server. I have declared it static.

But in client some values are 00 instead of values. I am printing the values just before

the server return call, its fine.
     But the same print statements are giving junk values in client.

```
    struct enc_request{
            int enc_len;
            unsigned char enc_msg[700];
    };

    in server proc:
    static enc_reply reply_e;
    return (&reply_e);
```

Can anyone please give some idea about what is wrong.

output:
 original reply send
114 105 107 104 051 089 076 069 097 083 051 100 053 078 066 054 054 109 106 106 077 055 102 056 114 043 121 103 068 103 073 115 109 043 087 108 111 080 118 052 110 080 114 047 065 104 097 097 051 084 068 080 102 065 054 080 114 073 116 106 084 084 110 109 088 076 116 110 070 087 105 104 043 111 104 074 074 066 052 052 066 120 098 116 107 047 104 089 115 080 097 119 097 111 103 043

reply received
114 105 107 104 051 089 076 069 097 083 051 100 053 078 066 054 054 109 106 106 077 055 102 056 114 043 121 103 068 103 073 115 109 043 087 108 111 080 118 052 110 080 114 047 065 104 097 097 051 084 068 080 102 065 054 080 114 073 116 106 084 084 110 109 088 076 116 110 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the entire situation but when making and receiving RPC requests the size of the data may be incorrect yielding the zeroes.  Are there mechanisms in place on both server and client that standardize the size of the `struct enc_reply`?  I've seen similar cases where a 32bit system is sending data to a 64bit and uses `sizeof()` to determine a structure's size which yielded unpredictable results across differing architectures.

Comment: Thanks! I am running on the same machine.

Comment: silly mistake.... wasted so much time :(, was changing size of struct enc_request instead of static enc_reply in interface.. sorry guys

Comment: At least you found what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing server and client code by yourself, use strength of rpcgen. 
- Compile the .x file using an option -a like :

```
 ~$ rpcgen -a filename.x
```

.
- the client and server files will get auto-generated.
- In the server file, the static variable of the type you want gets generated with name 'result'
- assign the struct members to result's members.
- at the client side, extract them.

The problem will be solved. Just try this !